# Example of 10-fold SVM classification in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I need a somehow descriptive example showing how to do a 10-fold SVM classification on a two class set of data. there is just one example in the MATLAB documentation but it is not with 10-fold. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's a complete example, using the following functions from the Bioinformatics Toolbox: [SVMTRAIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html), [SVMCLASSIFY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmclassify.html), [CLASSPERF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/classperf.html), [CROSSVALIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html).

```
load fisheriris                              %# load iris dataset
groups = ismember(species,'setosa');         %# create a two-class problem

%# number of cross-validation folds:
%# If you have 50 samples, divide them into 10 groups of 5 samples each,
%# then train with 9 groups (45 samples) and test with 1 group (5 samples).
%# This is repeated ten times, with each group used exactly once as a test set.
%# Finally the 10 results from the folds are averaged to produce a single 
%# performance estimation.
k=10;

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', groups, k);   %# get indices of 10-fold CV
cp = classperf(groups);                      %# init performance tracker

for i = 1:k                                  %# for each fold
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                %# get indices of test instances
    trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     %# get indices training instances

    %# train an SVM model over training instances
    svmModel = svmtrain(meas(trainIdx,:), groups(trainIdx), ...
                 'Autoscale',true, 'Showplot',false, 'Method','QP', ...
                 'BoxConstraint',2e-1, 'Kernel_Function','rbf', 'RBF_Sigma',1);

    %# test using test instances
    pred = svmclassify(svmModel, meas(testIdx,:), 'Showplot',false);

    %# evaluate and update performance object
    cp = classperf(cp, pred, testIdx);
end

%# get accuracy
cp.CorrectRate

%# get confusion matrix
%# columns:actual, rows:predicted, last-row: unclassified instances
cp.CountingMatrix
```

with the output:

```
ans =
      0.99333
ans =
   100     1
     0    49
     0     0
```

we obtained `99.33%` accuracy with only one 'setosa' instance mis-classified as 'non-setosa'

---

**UPDATE**: SVM functions have moved to Statistics toolbox in R2013a

Comment: Thanks for the nice example. A little confusion that I have. Suppose I have 50 entries in all. The above code divides it into 10 sets of 5 entries each and then use 9 to train and 1 to test in each iteration. But the usual flow should be a little different maybe, i.e. 1. train 2. cross validate repeat the above and then test? or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: @user488652: I'm not clear on your question, but the code above follows the standard method of [n-fold cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#K-fold_cross-validation)

Comment: @Amro Can you please explain `groups = ismember(species,'setosa');` Why have you used 'setosa' and not other two types of output. Also How can I use it for my dataset stored in a 25X5 matrix and results in 25X1 matrix with two outputs.

Comment: @MaxSteel: SVM at its core is a binary classification algorithm, so you cant have more than two classes (I arbitrarily chose setosa vs. non-setosa classes). Fortunately there are methods to extend SVM to support multi-class cases. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4980055/97160

Comment: Thank you for explanation Mr. Amro. Could you tell me how to plot a graph for `cp.CountingMatrix`? @Amro

Comment: @TARIQ: a bit off topic, but you could simply use `bar3` to plot the confusion matrix. If you have the Neural Networks toolbox, there's the [`plotconfusion`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotconfusion.html) function, otherwise you could manually do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7081430/97160

Comment: I would also like to add that if you want to combine cv with PCA you would perform PCA for each fold (every training set) and do the same transform for the testing data. See [crossvalidated] (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/linear-kernel-and-non-linear-kernel-for-support-vector-machine)

Comment: Arno, that is from some time ago, but if you still see that I have a question: Why do you get the Correctrate with cp.CorrectRate only outside of the classification loop? As far as I can see this only gives you the accuracy of the last crossvalidation loop (and not a mean over all the crossvalidation)...?

Comment: @Pegah: you should read the [CLASSPERF doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/classperf.html), my usage of the function is same as the example shown in the docs. First we initialize the `cp` object before the loop. Then inside the loop we update the `cp` object with the predictions of the current validation fold. The function will accumulate results each time you call it. So when we finish the loop the results returned will be the average over the K folds. btw the name is Amro not Arno :)

Comment: Sorry for the misspelling Amro (much nicer name btw)! Read it but still confused. E.g. when I have the following: CorrectRate(i)= cp.CorrectRate;inside the CV loop, the CorrectRate Array also updates obviously i-times, and its **last** instance (and not the mean of the array or so) will be equal to what a cp.CorrectRate outside the loop returns..

Comment: @Pegah: `cp.CorrectRate` returns the **current running average** (i.e rolling) of the classification precision and NOT the classification precision of the current fold. If you want the latter, use `cp.LastCorrectRate`