# Kfold cross validation different correct rate values

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I have a problem with the K fold cross validation in Matlab, actually I have used the function mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070789/example-of-10-fold-svm-classification-in-matlab).  The problem is that I get different Cp values every time I run my program.  I use the function to perform a feature selection procedure so I get a different subset feature every time.  Could you please help me to find a solution or to identify the problem source?

Comment: So, does my answer explain the issue?

Answer (score 1):

[`crossvalind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) randomly generates cross validation indexes, so this will be a non-deterministic process.  That's the source of your problem, but it is not unexpected.

The solution would be to save the training and testing sample indexes used for our feature selection.