# How to do cross validation SVM classifier

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to perform a decoding by applying an SVM classifier to a data matirx S, the size of which is 1089*43093,and the prediction accuracy of the labels, denoted as r, is calculated based on a 11-fold cross-validation classification procedure.The 11 fold cross-validation is based on the data matrix S, which is separated into the training and testing data sets for classification. Specifically, this cross-validation is only for calculating the prediction accuracy r.
Can anyone give me some suggestion to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use libsvm, helps to get started on svm..

Comment: is there any tutorial for me to read something about how to use libsvm?

Comment: I want to use matlab implement it

Comment: anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#matlab

Comment: i thought it was some Matlab code.

Comment: yes it is, you need to install the library and you can use SVM with it..

Comment: I googled it for you, i'm kind like that.  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/classificationsvm.crossval.html

Comment: when I use this:svmModel = svmtrain(meas(trainIdx,:),group(trainIdx),'Autoscale',true,... the error shows: "undefined variable meas" How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To carry out SVM classification, use [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/).

A good tutorial to start would be: https://sites.google.com/site/kittipat/libsvm_matlab

Matlab code for reference on cross validation:

[Example of 10-fold SVM classification in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070789/example-of-10-fold-svm-classification-in-matlab/3071938#3071938)

[Retraining after Cross Validation with libsvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047459/retraining-after-cross-validation-with-libsvm)

Installing LibSVM on MATLAB: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz_4h_bH7-c

Comment: Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
Could Not Find C:\D disk\MATLAB\R2014a\libsvm-3.18\matlab\svmtrain.exp

Could Not Find C:\D disk\MATLAB\R2014a\libsvm-3.18\matlab\svmtrain.exp

MEX completed successfully.

Comment: it cannot find svmtrain.exp

Comment: When I try to load s_matrix                            
              groups = ismember(s_matrix,'setosa'); it shows error like this:Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: How to fix this? I follow the steps on this website:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070789/example-of-10-fold-svm-classification-in-matlab/3071938#3071938

Comment: when I use this:svmModel = svmtrain(meas(trainIdx,:),group(trainIdx),'Autoscale',true,... the error shows: "undefined variable meas" How to fix this problem?

Comment: @ Parag S. Chandakkar,I still do not know how to code this question by following an example in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222661/how-to-fix-the-fisheriris-cross-classification?noredirect=1#comment39289610_25222661